# A topology in a Vector space

Tags: general-topology

Let $V$ a finite dimensional vector space and let $T$ the collection of all finite unions of vector subspaces of $V$, with the empty set. Show that the elements of $T$ are the closed sets of a topology in $V$ and determine all the irreducible sets.

I show the part of the topology, for the irreducible sets, i am not sure how to begin, but I guess that the irreducible sets are the vector subspaces, is it right? If so, how can I prove that?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, excuse me, I am working with the topology of closed sets.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts:

1. Show that a vector subspace is not the union of finitely many smaller vector subspaces, and
2. Show that the union of finitely many vector subspaces is not irreducible.

2 follows from the definition of irreducibility. 1 follows from a measure argument or dimension argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I must say that there is a mistake in the question, the collection $T$ it is not a topology.

Comment: @Miguemate Are you sure? It is closed under finite unions and I don't see how it could fail to be closed under infinite intersections

Comment: Hello @Brian Rushton, but how can i prove that the arbitray intersection of finite unions is finite?

Comment: @Miguemate The intersection lies in each finite union that you are intersecting, so lies in those finitely many subspaces V_1,...,V_n. Each V_i might split into smaller pieces when intersecting with another finite union, but doing so only splits it into finitely many smaller pieces. Each of these can split, but because the dimension is finite, the process terminates.